# How do I display all user roles for users in my database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to show all roles for users that are in my database. I'm using a LINQ query that I found on another SO posting. I'm having trouble with the snippet of code in my view and I'm getting this error: CS0103: The name 'AllUsers' does not exist in the current context. Here's my code...

ViewModel:

```
     public class MyViewModel
     {
         public IEnumerable<MyUser> AllUsers { get; set; }
         public List<MyUser> myList { get; set; }
     }
```

Controller:

```
    public class RoleController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetUsers()
        {
            var roles = from MembershipUser u in Membership.GetAllUsers()
                    select new MyUser
                    {
                        User = u,
                        UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)
                    };

            List<MyUser> res = new List<MyUser>();

            foreach (MyUser u in roles)
                res.Add(u);

            MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel { AllUsers = res };

            return View(model);
       }
   }
```

View (snippet):

```
<td>
  @if(!(bool)(ViewBag.UserNameIsFound != null))
  {                      
     @Html.ActionLink("Add as user", "CreateUser", "Account")
     <br />                     
     foreach (MyUser u in Model.AllUsers)
     {
         foreach (string role in u.UserRoles)
         {
              AllUsers = MyList.Add(currItem);
              Console.WriteLine(role + "<br />");
         }
     }
 } 
</td>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats at the top of your view, which says what type of model it takes? :)

Comment: i'm using another viewmodel which is why i'm running into this issue

Comment: is there any way around this?

Comment: I have tried combining the second one with the first viewmodel but am still getting the same error message.

Comment: you need the View to take the same type as you pass into View(model);

Comment: the error is basically saying, when it compiles your page, it has no idea what AllUsers is, meaning whatever type it thinks it is, is not the type you think it is....

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the following line of your view.
I don't know what is a variable named 'AllUsers' and why AllUsers is here?

```
AllUsers = MyList.Add(currItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get, what the 10th line means:

```
<td>
  @if(!(bool)(ViewBag.UserNameIsFound != null))
  {                      
     @Html.ActionLink("Add as user", "CreateUser", "Account")
     <br />                     
     foreach (MyUser u in Model.AllUsers)
     {
         foreach (string role in u.UserRoles)
         {
              // what means the next line? what is "AllUsers"?
10:           AllUsers = MyList.Add(currItem);
              Console.WriteLine(role + "<br />");
         }
     }
 } 
</td>
```

What is `AllUsers`? I do not see it declared as a local variable. 
If you mean `Model.AllUsers`, then you will iterate through the initial `Model.AllUsers` and will constantly change it to a new one. That is also not very clear.
Try to comment out the 10th line.

Comment: I commented it out but still have Model.AllUsers in the outer loop. How can I fix this?

Comment: You should tell the compiler the type of the model.  You should type `@model NameSpace.MyViewModel` at the very top of the file